# Proving or disproving continuity of $f(x+a)=\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $f$ be defined $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and let
$$
f(x+a)=\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}
$$
hold for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is periodic with a period of $4a$ and using that, check if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

So I've proven the part that it's periodic, that was simple:

$$
f(x+4a)=\frac{1+f(x+3a)}{1-f(x+3a)} = \frac{1+\frac{1+f(x+2a)}{1-f(x+2a)}}{1-\frac{1+f(x+2a)}{1-f(x+2a)}}=\cdots=\frac{-2f(x)}{-2}=f(x), \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

But now I can't seem to figure out how to use the fact that $f$ is periodic to prove or disprove it's continuity. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way how to show it without using the periodicity, I hope that is ok aswell.

First, $f$ must omit the value $1$ because otherwise the above fraction would be undefined. From this it follows, that $f$ omits the values $-1,0$ aswell.
If $f$ was continuous its whole image lies in one of the following connected sets: $(-\infty,-1), (-1,0), (0,1), (1,\infty)$.

The first is impossible because $\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)} < -1$ implies $2<0$ if the denominator is positive.

The second is imposible because $\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}$ is positive if $f(x)\in(-1,0)$.

The third is impossible because $\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}>1$ if $f(x)\in(0,1)$.

The fourth is impossible because $\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)} < 0$ if $f(x)>1$.